# Implement an iOS barcode reader apps

Tags: ios

I'm planning to develop a simple barcode reader for iOS that will read the barcode and return all the information it can extract from the internet.
So far I decided to use the ZBar SDK in the app and successfully read the barcode which return a decoded string of the barcode. 
Now I wonder how can I extract the useful information from it. I have limited knowledge on barcode so I suppose there will be an online database so that I can input the barcode result and fetch the data from it.
Can anyone give me some suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to have an online or local database with scanned barcodes that are linked with lets say products or something. The barcode that you scan will match with the ones in Database and return you the product id or product details.

Comment: have you got my point? @user1242836

Comment: Check out http://www.upcdatabase.com/. Also, amazon.com uses a book's ISBN # as part of the URL.. so you could at least possibly point to a book's page on amazon after scanning it.

Comment: @AhmedZ.yeah I got your idea, and I kinda figure it out, the thing I 'm concerned about is which online database is available for me to use.

Answer (score -1):

Zxing the best library for Bar code and QR Code scan It Support both Android and iPhone SDK. This is used by most of the commercial mobile cash application

[More Information on ZXING](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)

Also there is anther library 
ZBar. Seems to be a very capable library.

Good luck
Chamath Jeevan

Comment: This is a api/sdk for android. It only has a QR code reader for iOS.